# Group multiple columns and rank within the group power query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, ranking

I am trying to create a rank column by multiple fields and within individual groups. The purpose is to allow me to easily select the top 10 values for a set context. While this is theoretically possible in a DAX measure (for a dynamic context) in Power Pivot and Power Bi, it does not seem that it is possible to filter by a measure in a pivot table.

Below is the table transformation I want to do.

| GroupField1 | GroupField2 | RankField1 | RankField2 | OtherField |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y | A | 25 | 10 | data |
| X | B | 30 | 12 | data |
| Y | A | 20 | 10 | data |
| X | B | 15 | 10 | data |
| Z | Q | 5 | 5 | data |

Transforms to :

| GroupField1 | GroupField2 | RankField1 | RankField2 | OtherField | Rank1 | Rank2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y | A | 25 | 10 | data | 2 | 2 |
| X | B | 30 | 12 | data | 1 | 1 |
| Y | A | 20 | 10 | data | 3 | 2? |
| X | B | 15 | 10 | data | 4 | 2? |
| Z | Q | 5 | 5 | data | 5 | 3 |

Comment: You state: "The purpose is to allow me to easily select the top 10 values for a given context." Precomputing rank in PQ will not allow you to do this. The context will always be the precomputed one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a custom function to accomplish this

1. Group into nested tables
2. Process the nested tables to add the rankings
3. Expand the appropriate columns to return the table to its original form + the Rank columns

   ```
    RankGroup = (UnRanked as table, GroupFields as list, RankFields as list, RankNames as list) as table => let 
    //Group by GroupFields
    Grouped = Table.Group(UnRanked, GroupFields, {{"Ranked", each _}}),

    // Ranks Subfunction
    Ranks = (InVal as table, NewCols as list, Fields as list) as any => let
        // Soon to be replaceable Rank Function
        Rank = (InVal as table, NewCol as text, Field as text) as table => Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.Sort(InVal, {{Field, Order.Descending}}), NewCol),
        result = List.Accumulate(
            List.Positions(NewCols), InVal, (value, index) => Rank(value, NewCols{index}, Fields{index})
            )
        in 
            result,
    // Process each Group
    Ranked = Table.TransformColumns(Grouped, {"Ranked" ,each Ranks(_, RankFields, RankNames)}),
    // Only Expand the columns that are not represented in the Grouped table
    Expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Ranked, "Ranked", List.RemoveItems(RankNames & Table.ColumnNames(UnRanked), GroupFields))
    in 
    Expanded
   ```

Note that the Rank function has a soon coming replacement (My Excel installation does not have this feature) [Table.AddRankColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-addrankcolumn)

However, this can easily be accomplished using DAX in Power BI or Power Pivot:
For an individual calculated rank within a particular group, we can use the RANKX function

```
Rank rows in a group RANKX ( 
FILTER( 'SourceTable',
    'SourceTable'[GroupByField1] = EARLIER('SourceTable'[GroupByField1]) &&
    'SourceTable'[GroupByField2] = EARLIER('SourceTable'[GroupByField2])
    ),
 'SourceTable'[RankField])
```

This DAX expression is adapted from [Databear.com RANKX](https://databear.com/how-to-use-the-dax-rankx-function-in-power-bi/)